# Creating a circle mesh in c#

Tags: c#, directx, geometry

I am creating in programm in which the users can create 2d shapes (circle, triangle, rectangle) in a 3d room.

For an 2d rectangle i can use `Mesh.Box` but how can I create a triangle or a circle?

I found that website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153276(v=vs.85).aspx

Can I transform that infos on my problem? can someone give me an example?

Comment: Mesh.Box is not 2d rectangle, that's a 3D cube, by the way, managed DirectX has been deprecate for several years, why do you still use that?

Comment: Hi, when i set the depth in Mesh.Box to 0 then i get a 2d rectangle. I use it because its a wish by my university

Comment: This is using SlimDX instead of Managed DirectX, but here are list of primitives for one of my projects : https://github.com/mrvux/FeralTic/tree/master/Core/DX11/Geometry/Primitives Hope that helps (even if syntax will be slightly different)